# Is stackOverFlow site developed in the MVC pattern?

Tags: discussion

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What was Stack Overflow built with?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10369/what-was-stack-overflow-built-with)

What was Stack Overflow developed with? It looks like ASP.NET MVC. Is it?

Comment: Not a question...

Comment: It is a question.  Just one that belongs on meta.stackoverflow.com.

Comment: Belongs on meta I think.

Comment: @Cullen: Your accept rate is only 8%.  You will probably get more and better help if you accept more answers to your questions.

Comment: @Eric: Thanks for pointing that out.  I didn't take the time to find out what the percentage meant for one thing.  I try my best to be a responsible participant.  I don't want to mark a reply as an answer if it is not one so as not to miss lead other users in thinking that's the solution.  I'll go through my questions and mark whatever I negelected to mark as answers.

Comment: No.  SO more closely follows the 6to8wks pattern.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2008/09/what-was-stack-overflow-built-with/

Comment: Thanks Robert, this is exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: @robert Thank for this information